# What are the differences in Leetha's powers, and Spawns personal powers?

Tags: magic, magical-theory, spawn, symbiotes

Al Simmons, aka the most well regarded and arguably powerful Hell Spawn of modern/current Earth, was bonded to the symbiotic suit, K-7 Leetha, back in the very first issue. This entity/suit is a living thing that is "bonded to his central nervous system", and thus works *literally* like an extension of his own body. However, it is later revealed that the suit and its host are *still* essentially two separate entities with their own distinct energies and powers, working together as one seamlessly under control of the host to function as one entity.

in **Spawn # 19** Harry Houdini [yes, *that* Harry Houdini, apparently] meets up with Spawn and teaches him the fundamentals of magic. Houdini has evolved from being a mere mortal to a being of true magic, and had his own machinations...

[image]

[image]

...but he *did* give Al some helpful tutelage, not the least of which is that Spawn's suit has its own energy or life force, apparently.  This is significant, because initially, Spawn had a "limited pool of Necroplasmic energy" from which his strongest powers [teleportation, matter manipulation, energy blasts, self healing] could pull from.

[image]

The above mentioned powers weren't total examples, however. Also, the distinction between *Leetha's powers* and *Al's* power seems... murky, at best. This is *further* complicated by the fact that *some* of Al's "overall" powers can be recharged by absorbing "latent evil", basically feeding or drawing form the "evil aura" of others. To my knowledge, its never really stated *how* this works, though, as in if it "add points" to his diminishing necroplasmic units, or if it "boosts" the effects of the same unit use [essentially turning TNT into C-4], or if it grants him energy the way a human sleeping grants him physical refreshment.

So the questions are:

1. **What exactly are Spawns PERSONAL Powers, abilities and limitations?**
2. **What are his COSTUME's abilities, powers and limitations?**

Comment: @Rushiro, I don't know much about Spawn, but, looking at your question, I'd say that you have multiple things asked in one question (it will be considered as *too-broad*). I guess you'd need to separate them or focus on only one aspect.

Comment: @Shreedhar perhaps if I just got rid of the last two elements? Number 3 would require too much checking throughout the various issues, and 4 isn;t really directly attached, as it involves whole new powers from a different source. so perhaps that would make things easier to answer, don;t you think?

Comment: I suppose the first two fit and they can be assumed to be one question.. Spawn's vs Leetha's powers and limitations

Comment: @Shreedhar Great. I'll make the adjustments, and just add the supplementary questions here.

Comment: For anyone willing to check them out, the supplementary questions are:
3. **How do Spawn and Leetha's powers work together, and what are the differences between them?**
 4.  How have the various changes to Spawn  (his empowerment from **The Green** amongst other stuff, for instance] changed this in any way?